# Can multiple objects be inserted with the << operator in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**Could I write the following ...**

```
      raw_data.categories.each do |category|
          obj.categories << category
      end
```

**As the following instead? ...**

```
      obj.categories << raw_data.categories
```

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Did *you* try it?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Yes, and it didn't work. But Mori's solution below works perfectly!

Comment: @Ryan Bigg: Excuse me, I'm not the one who asked a question that showed no research effort. I'll remove my -1 and give the questioner the benefit of the doubt, though. (EDIT: That is, I'd be happy to remove it if the questioner could edit the question, since my vote is locked in right now. Sorry for the inconvenience)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
obj.categories |= raw_data.categories
```

Comment: This is probably the *right* thing to do here, but it is *not* equivalent to the previous code. `obj.categories += raw_data.categories` is closer to the @Jacob's code, but `obj.categories.concat(raw_data.categories)` or `obj.categories.push(*raw_data.categories)` is equivalent to the @Jacob's code.

Comment: @Mori: What's the difference between the `+=` you had before and the `|=` now? The += worked as well.

Comment: @Jacob, read Mr. Lafortune's (most excellent) answer below, it describes the difference. I haven't checked to see if rails suppresses duplicate associations, which would make them effectively the same.

Comment: @Mori: The answer is actually BM5k's, I only edited it for formatting :-)

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at `Array#<<` and `Array#push`.

`Array#<<` takes one which is appended in place to given array. For example:

```
irb> array = %w[ a b c ]       # => ["a", "b", "c"]
irb> array << 'd'              # => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

however, if you pass an array, you'll be surprised at the result

```
irb> array << ['e', 'f', 'g']  # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", ["e", "f", "g"]]
```

`Array#push` can handle 1+ objects, each of which are appended to the array.

```
irb> array = %w[ a b c ]         # => ["a", "b", "c"]
irb> array.push 'd'              # => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

However, calling `#push` with an array gives you the same result as `#<<`.

```
irb> array.push ['e', 'f', 'g']  # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", ["e", "f", "g"]]
```

In order to push all of the elements in the array, just add a `*` before the second array.

```
irb> array.push *['e', 'f', 'g']  # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

On a related note, while `Array#+` does concatenate the arrays, it will also allow duplicate values.

```
irb> array  = %w[ a b c ]         # => ["a", "b", "c"]
irb> array += ['d']               # => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
irb> array += ['d']               # => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d"]
```

If this is undesired, the `|` operator will return a union of two arrays, without duplicate values.

```
irb> array  = %w[ a b c ]         # => ["a", "b", "c"]
irb> array |= ['d']               # => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
irb> array |= ['d']               # => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```