# Getting ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid on save many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models to describe a many-to-many relationship between steps and product:

```
class Step < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :steps
end

class ProductsStep < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :step
end
```

And these are my tables:

**steps:**

```
   Column    |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | bigint                      | not null default nextval('steps_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name        | character varying           | not null                                           | extended |              | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone |                                                    | plain    |              | 
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone |                                                    | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "steps_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_steps_on_weeks_id" btree (weeks_id)
```

**products:**

```
      Column       |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                 | bigint                      | not null default nextval('products_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name               | character varying           | not null                                              | extended |              | 
 photo_file_name    | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              | 
 photo_content_type | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              | 
 photo_file_size    | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 photo_updated_at   | timestamp without time zone |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null                                              | plain    |              | 
 updated_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null                                              | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "products_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

**products_steps:**

```
   Column   |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 step_id    | integer                     | not null  | plain   |              | 
 product_id | integer                     | not null  | plain   |              | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain   |              | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "products_steps_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (product_id, step_id)
```

I would like to save the products with the associated steps, but I'm receiving the following message:

> Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 81ms (ActiveRecord: 10.6ms)
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (The validation failed: Steps isn't valid)

I did the following:

```
def create
    steps = Array.new()
    params[:product][:steps].split(/,/).each do |s|
      steps << s.to_i
    end
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.steps << Step.where(:id => steps)

    puts "#{@product.steps.first.name}" #the name is printed
    product = Product.find_by(name: @product.name, brand: @product.brand)
    if product.nil?
      if @product.save!
        render :json => {:status => :success}
      end
    end
  end
```

The steps params is a string like "1,2,3" that represents the step id.

I have no idea what I did wrong, I did exactly the same thing in other situations and it worked.

**EDIT:**

Here is all my request and the errors message, including the sugested validation:

```
Bad request content body
Started POST "/products/?product[name]=test+1&product[brand]=test&product[released_for]=Low+Poo&product[weight]=50.0&product[measurement]=g&product[steps]=1%2C2%2C3&product[user_id]=test%40gmail.com&" for 192.168.2.5 at 2018-06-19 17:56:23 -0300
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"product"=>{"name"=>"test 1", "brand"=>"test", "released_for"=>"Low Poo", "weight"=>"50.0", "measurement"=>"g", "steps"=>"1,2,3", "user_id"=>"test@gmail.com"}}
Unpermitted parameter: :steps
  Step Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "steps".* FROM "steps" WHERE "steps"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2], ["id", 3]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:73
------LOGS-------
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f2840acb628 @base=#<Product id: nil, name: "Test 1", brand: "Test", measurement: "g", weight: #<BigDecimal:7f28409f2ee0,'0.5E2',9(18)>, photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, released_for: "Low Poo", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: "test@gmail.com">, @messages={:steps=>["não é válido"]}, @details={:steps=>[{:error=>:invalid}, {:error=>:invalid}, {:error=>:invalid}]}>
-------------
Hidratação
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."name" = $1 AND "products"."brand" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["name", "Test 1"], ["brand", "Test"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:78
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f2840acb628 @base=#<Product id: nil, name: "Test 1", brand: "Test", measurement: "g", weight: #<BigDecimal:7f28409f2ee0,'0.5E2',9(18)>, photo_file_name: nil, photo_content_type: nil, photo_file_size: nil, photo_updated_at: nil, released_for: "Low Poo", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: "test@gmail.com">, @messages={:steps=>["não é válido"]}, @details={:steps=>[{:error=>:invalid}, {:error=>:invalid}, {:error=>:invalid}]}>
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:82
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:82
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 75ms (ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (A validação falhou: Steps não é válido):

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:82:in `create'
```

Comment: Posting an image of your table is not recommended. Can you please copy the text and paste it as code?

Comment: can you do `@product.valid? ? @product.save! : Rails.logger.warn @producer.errors.inspect` and give us the log output?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question

Comment: Could you please provide a full log from log/development.log? There's clearly some info missing here

Comment: @MikeSzyndel i did that, added all my request log

Comment: `@product.steps << Step.where(:id => steps)` will try to push an array of steps into your association `Step.where` returns an array, so you're essentially saying `[] << []` which will result in `[[]]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8304145/143238

Comment: On top of what @BM5k I would also save `@product` before adding the steps to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation failed: Steps isn't valid. This means that step id which you are passing is not valid. you can print @product and @product.steps to check what is printing. When i check code  `@product.steps << Step.where(:id => steps)` this code will make array of array so it must be  `@product.steps = Step.where(:id => steps)` or  `@product.steps += Step.where(:id => steps)`. Print @product and @product.steps this will give clear detail what data is trying to save in table.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Please see what Rohan wrote

Comment: The validation failed: Steps isn't valid, this indicate step id not able to create because step has not passed validation. Why it is not getting crated that will be clear once Rohan will puts product object and step. i am thinking  it is becasue @product.steps << Step.where(:id => steps),  this line will insert array inside array so step will be [[1,2,3]] but it should be [1,2,3]

Comment: No. Steps are not valid because they are not permitted in params. Validation may not be specified explicitly in the model but come from Rails association. Your advice is wrong and dangerous, bypassing Rails security features.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description shared it seems like there could one of the below mentioned issues which could be raising the exception.

Firstly, the below mentioned log trail shows that only steps is not permitted apart from that all other parameter is being permitted to the database.

```
Parameters: {"product"=>{"name"=>"test 1", "brand"=>"test", "released_for"=>"Low Poo", "weight"=>"50.0", "measurement"=>"g", "steps"=>"1,2,3", "user_id"=>"test@gmail.com"}}
Unpermitted parameter: :steps
```

So, does the user_id column has a datatype string, also could not find the user_id column in the table structure shared.

Secondly, for the ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, this is raised when a validation is failed for the corresponding model.

Please check if there are any validation failure happening for the above case.